# Realm Notification Blocks Performance

Tags: ios, realm

I'm curious about the performance characteristics of Realm notifications in Obj-C/Swift, specifically object notifications.

- Are there a maximum number of notification blocks allowed to be registered?
- Are notifications cheap?
- Are there practical limitations to having many of them registered e.g. if there are 1000x object notifications registered all on separate objects, assuming that only a fraction would ever update at the same time (~30) would there be realistically any cause for concern?

Comment: While the questions are valid - they are pretty broad. Are notifications cheap? By comparison to what? Cheaper than.....? Can you provide a use case where you would have 1000 totally unrelated objects being observed? Typically there would be some correlation between them and in that case, you would be observing a set of X number of objects and a 1000 of them is pretty tiny by comparison to observing 1M. We may be able to help if you can further clarify the question. Also, are you talking about a local database, ROS or something else?

Comment: More specifics - we have 1 realm object / table that has a _typename and _filterKey property because we don't know the shape of the object ahead of time. However, we know that we group certain objects by _typename and _filterKey. We index on _typename. Each UI component in the app will have a different (_typename, _filterKey) pair that will be triggered on. For most components these pairs correlate with singular objects. For TableViews and CollectionViews they are lists but those lists will have each have potentially separate singular objects as well. I.e. lots of heterogenous and dynamic UI.

Comment: We want to be able to notify of changes on many of these various objects as new data arrives from the server, which may update lists or singular objects (so update within a cycle or two of the runloop after transaction write completes). We do not want to use ROS.

Comment: Last bit of data - actual payload is stored as a string on the object. We handle serialization on the application side, already have that working to our needs.

Comment: The use case is still very unclear. Since *We do not want to use ROS.* what's the use case? Is this going to be realm running on a single workstation or what? *we don't know the shape of the object ahead of time* so the objects are dynamic and created on the fly? That's going to be a challenge as Realm Result is a homogenous collection type, so you can't store different subclasses of Object in the same Results object - all objects with that results must be identical. Because of that you won't be able to do any queries. Not sure if that's a factor or not.

Comment: This is iOS (tagged) and what we do have for querying is the concept of a `(_typename, _filterKey)` pair returned by the server + a sortKey in certain cases. Views are aware of the `(_typename, _filterKey)` pairs that they query for and for lists _sortKey to order by. What is dynamic is the string data payload and that piece is ingested and determines rendering (which we've already figured out). So what views at different stages of the app do know ahead of time is query for this pair and sort, ingest this string payload and render. What I'd like every view to do is update when payload changes.

Comment: `Object { _typename, _filterKey, _sortKey, payload }` is the shape